# How to fix text via the module testinfra?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, testinfra

wrote a dockerfile. in it, I run the test using module testinfra. image module, which is used in the dockerile FROM alpine:3.11

there is such an error

```
Step 24/27 : RUN py.test /etc/nginx/test/test.py
 ---> Running in 595d6978e9a4
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-6.2.3, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /etc/nginx/test
plugins: testinfra-6.2.0
collected 3 items

../../../etc/nginx/test/test.py ..F                                      [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________ test_nginx_running_and_enabled[local] _____________________

host = <testinfra.host.Host local>

    def test_nginx_running_and_enabled(host):
        nginx = host.service('nginx')
>       assert nginx.is_running

/etc/nginx/test/test.py:12: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testinfra/modules/service.py:107: in is_running
    [0, 1, 3, 8], "%s %s status", self._service_command, self.name
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testinfra/utils/__init__.py:29: in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testinfra/modules/service.py:95: in _service_command
    return self.find_command("service")
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testinfra/modules/base.py:53: in find_command
    return cls._host.find_command(*args, **kwargs)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <testinfra.host.Host local>, command = 'service'
extrapaths = ('/sbin', '/usr/sbin')

    def find_command(self, command, extrapaths=("/sbin", "/usr/sbin")):
        """Return path of given command
    
        raise ValueError if command cannot be found
        """
        out = self.run_expect([0, 1, 127], "command -v %s", command)
        if out.rc == 0:
            return out.stdout.rstrip("\r\n")
        for basedir in extrapaths:
            path = os.path.join(basedir, command)
            if self.exists(path):
                return path
>       raise ValueError('cannot find "{}" command'.format(command))
E       ValueError: cannot find "service" command

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testinfra/host.py:46: ValueError
```

for some reason, it does not want to check whether nginx is running and whether it is enabled, as I understand it, it does not find the service function itself

the test code looks like this

```
import testinfra
def test_os_release(host):
 assert host.file("/etc/os-release").contains("Alpine Linux")

def test_nginx_is_installed(host):
    nginx = host.package('nginx')
    assert nginx.is_installed
    assert nginx.version.startswith('1.16.1')

def test_nginx_running_and_enabled(host):
    nginx = host.service('nginx')
    assert nginx.is_running
    assert nginx.is_enabled
```

dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.11

ADD https://dl.bintray.com/php-alpine/key/php-alpine.rsa.pub /etc/apk/keys/php-alpine.rsa.pub

# make sure you can use HTTPS
RUN apk --update add ca-certificates
RUN echo "https://dl.bintray.com/php-alpine/v3.11/php-7.4" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# Install packages
RUN apk --no-cache add php php-fpm php-opcache php-openssl php-curl \
    nginx supervisor curl

# Install python/pip/setuptools/testinfra
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip install pytest-testinfra

#create folder for tests
RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx/test
COPY test.py /etc/nginx/test

# https://github.com/codecasts/php-alpine/issues/21
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/php7 /usr/bin/php

# Configure nginx
COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Remove default server definition
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Configure PHP-FPM
COPY config/fpm-pool.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY config/php.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/custom.ini

# Configure supervisord
COPY config/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Setup document root
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

# Make sure files/folders needed by the processes are accessable when they run under the nobody user
RUN chown -R nobody.nobody /var/www/html && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /run && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/lib/nginx && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/log/nginx

# Switch to use a non-root user from here on
USER nobody

# Add application
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --chown=nobody src/ /var/www/html/

#start test
RUN py.test /etc/nginx/test/test.py

# Expose the port nginx is reachable on
EXPOSE 8080

# Let supervisord start nginx & php-fpm
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]

# Configure a healthcheck to validate that everything is up&running
HEALTHCHECK --timeout=10s CMD curl --silent --fail http://127.0.0.1:8080/fpm-ping
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure but i think you should try add in your Dockerfile openrc package. In basic alpine images there is no command like 'service'.

```
RUN apk --update add openrc --no-cache
```

EDIT: 
as you can see testinfra looking for bin on tested host that's why raise the error. 
 `out = self.run_expect([0, 1, 127], "command -v %s", command)`

In case like this i recommend to use https://command-not-found.com/ to find package and installation command on many Linux distros.